# how can create file in flash drive and don't allow delete permission for any user

Tags: file

how can create file in flash drive  and  don't allow  delete permission for any user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible..

Explanation.
Most usb devices use fat32. hence all the user has to do is take it to another pc and format it.

Comment: Well you can format a usb device as non fat32 right? I have seen options for NTFS, would it be possible under other file systems?

Comment: http://hype-free.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-does-panda-usb-vaccination-work.html How does the Panda USB vaccination work?

Comment: @javed: Not sure if you can format it as NTFS. even if you can do so the user can always format it again.